# Why does PHP break my CSS?

Tags: php, forms, message, contacts, mailer

[image: screen shot]

I have recently created a contact form with PHP mailer which is finally working. However the success message is breaking my page and displaying in the top left corner instead of underneath the form. As you can see below.

This is the HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
       <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <td><label for="name" class="g">Name</label></td>
            <td><input id="name" name="name" type="text" autofocus></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="address" class="g">Address</label></td>
            <td><textarea rows="3" id="address" name="address" cols="50"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="number" class="g">Contact number</label></td>
            <td><input id="number" name="number" type="text" autofocus></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="email" class="g">Email</label></td>
            <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" autofocus></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><label for="message" class="g">Enquiry</label></td>
            <td><textarea rows="3" id="message" name="message" cols="50"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
            <?php
            if ($success) {
                echo $success;
            }
            ?>

            </form>
```

It also creates a huge blank white area in the middle of my page under the form. Does anyone know why this is? or how I would go about debugging it?

Comment: Inspect your success element with a tool like firebug. Maybe some CSS rules you have are causing this, it doesn't look like to be the code you provided here.

Comment: your echo $success is after you close </table> tag so .. its not in tags perhaps?

Comment: please close all input tags like this
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

Comment: can you post the link where this error is occur? I will try to solve it.

Comment: First off - using Firefox's firebug, you can look at the constructed HTML including what the PHP injects into the page before it reaches your browser.  There should be an equivalent for Chrome as well.  This will let you see exactly what HTML you're working with.  However, the main thing I see is that there's no container for the success message to go into.  I also don't really see any CSS.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe before it reaches your browser? Firebug is a browser tool, and it's displaying **parsed/rendered** html..

Comment: Here is where it is uploaded:

http://thatgirlnicola.com/reef/contact.php

Comment: I have created a new div to place it in and have styled it accordingly but on submit it is still appearing in the top  left corner..

Comment: @Niek van der Steen - yes, exactly.  The PHP injects HTML into the page before it reaches the browser, so the browser tool sees the post-PHP html structure.

Answer (score 3):

You should put this in a div or a span

```
<div style="text-align:center;"> <?php
        if ($success) {
            echo $success;
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: In that case he can have a defined class and use that in class attribute :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this and it still appears in the top left. When I check the console it is the first object within the body.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
 <form method="POST">
   <table border="1">
        <tr>
        <td><label for="name" class="g">Name</label></td>
        <td><input id="name" name="name" type="text" autofocus></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="address" class="g">Address</label></td>
        <td><textarea rows="3" id="address" name="address" cols="50"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="number" class="g">Contact number</label></td>
        <td><input id="number" name="number" type="text" autofocus></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="email" class="g">Email</label></td>
        <td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" autofocus></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="message" class="g">Enquiry</label></td>
        <td><textarea rows="3" id="message" name="message" cols="50"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if ($success) {?>

            <tr><td colspan="2">

            <?php echo $success; ?>
           </td></tr>
        <?php }
        ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

        </form>
```

Comment: @NicolaConeelee Post the link of your site, I also want to see where is is?

Comment: @NicolaConeelee hmmm, check your code first. may be the $success variable is also add anywhere else also in your code that is showing the message above. and use `if (!empty($success))` instead of `if ($success)`